# EE 5.3.2 - missing Upload Directory Synchronize function

Tags: control-panel, ee5

Recently updated to EE 5.3.2 and i am no longer able synchronize my upload directory folders.

According to docs, i should have a Synch button under Files, but nothing there.
https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/control-panel/file-manager.html#sync-directory

Any ideas? Am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

OK, apparently those who worked on UX/UI of EE5 didn't realize how unbelievably unnoticeable their solution is.

You have to click on a Upload Directory, then up-top where it the header for FILE MANAGER exists, a new icon appears to sync. Great Job! really user friendly!

Comment: This one caught me off guard, too. You expect there to be a button in the body area that says "Sync" or something.

Comment: Right, like EE2 used to have.